# Some javascript syntax that I dont understand

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

I am working with the karma.js library right now.  I was walking through there example project and came across some code that I don't really understand.  I am sure it is easy enough, but an explanation would be very helpful in understanding what the lib is doing.  From what I can understand it is looping through the files in the `__karma__` object and doing some kind of regex matching in the if statement with `/Spec\.js$/`.

```
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
    if (/Spec\.js$/.test(file)) {
        tests.push(file);
    }
}
```

If that is a regex matching, you can go from a string directly to access an object in javascript.  That is really interesting.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a `for-in` loop. It looks through the enumerable properties of an object. So for instance, if you have:

```
var obj = {
   a: 42,
   b: 27
};
```

...then within the loop, `file` will be `"a"` on one pass and `"b"` on another (but the order is not defined).

The `var` in it is just declaring a variable. Note that unlike some other languages, the variable is **not** limited in scope to just the loop, the declaration is function-wide.

The regex, `/Spec\.js$/`, is checking to see if the string *ends with* `"Spec.js"`. In a regex, `$` matches "end of line/input". A backslash is needed before the `.` because an unescaped `.` matches any character.

More about `for-in`:

- ...in [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4).
- ...on [my blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html).

More about `var`:

- ...on [my blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html).

Comment: How about the regex part?

Comment: @jhamm: Ah, missed that bit. Added.

Answer (score 0):

`/Spec\.js$/` is not string but a regular expression literal. What's essentially doing is:

```
var re = new RegExp('Spec\.js$');
re.test(file)
```

See MDN article on Regular Expressions for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

You indeed can go directly from a literal value into accessing its properties in JavaScript:

```
/^regex$/.test(...)

"a string".split(...)
```

etc. it all works.

With numbers however you need special treatment:

```
(1).toString()
```